# query in mongodb shell gives SyntaxError: missing : after property id @(shell):1:19

Tags: mongodb

I wanted to combine something like this *name does not end in "acid" and size does not range between 0.7 and 0.8* in mongodb and here is my query:

`db.mgodemo.find({"name" : {$ne: {$regex:".*acid.*"}}}, {"height":{$gt: 0.7}, "height":{$lt: 0.8}}).count()`

But I'm getting this error *[thread1] SyntaxError: missing : after property id @(shell):1:19*.

Did I missed some brackets? Hope someone could help me with it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this once

```
db.mgodemo.find({"name" : {$ne: {$regex:".*acid.*"}}}, {"height":{$lt: 0.7, $gt: 0.8}}).count()
```

Comment: So the above query works, but the result isn't right. Now, I have `db.demo.find({"name" : {$ne: {$regex:".*acid.*"}}}, {$or: [{"height":{$lt: 0.7}}, {"height":{$gt: 0.8}}] }).count()
` this query. It works, but the result isn't right, too. I think the regex part needs to be changed. I hope you can help me

Comment: Try now I have edited the post please share the json of you schema to get an idea.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The problem I got, has already been solved.

Comment: Ohh great to heard it (y)